# For some reason this is not doing anything, I think it may be the button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a webpage that when you put a number in the box, and press a button, it tells you if the number is even or odd in the console, but when I press submit, it doesn't do anything.

This is my code, is there anything I should change or fix?
I thought it would tell me if it was even or odd but it didn't do that.

```
const num = document.getElementById("numberText");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const button = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

function isEven(number){
    if (number % 2 === 0) {
        return "this number is even";
    } else {
        return "this number is odd";
    }
}

if (button.clicked == true) {
    console.log(isEven(num));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing wrong is checking if button is clicked. Please look into event handling and event listeners. You can learn more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp). Check out example below. If there is something wrong or confusing, please share it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Even or Odd Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="numberText" placeholder="Enter a number">
    <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script>
        const num = document.getElementById("numberText");
        const result = document.getElementById("result");
        const button = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

        function isEven(number) {
            if (number % 2 === 0) {
                return "This number is even";
            } else {
                return "This number is odd";
            }
        }

        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const inputValue = parseInt(num.value);
            const message = isEven(inputValue);
            result.textContent = message;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you make two other constants inside the event listener?

Comment: No particular reason. Could have done it in one line without making new variables. Just thought this way would be more readable and more self explanatory or easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish for little more elaborate...

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form');

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault(); // desactivate form submiting redirection
  
  myForm.MsgOut.textContent = 
     `Number (${ myForm.inputNum.value            }) is ` 
           + ( ( myForm.inputNum.valueAsNumber & 1 ) 
               ? 'odd' 
               : 'even'
             );
        
  setTimeout(()=>{ myForm.MsgOut.textContent = '...'}, 3000); 
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form"> 
  <input name="inputNum" type="number" placeHolder="enter a number" required>
  <button> test !</button>
  <br><br>
  <output name="MsgOut">...</output>
</form>
```

Comment: This is still a little bit more complicated for me— I'm still a beginner in Javascript! Sorry lol

Answer (score 0):

There's basically 2 things missing in your code:

1. You need to add an event listener to the button to trigger the function when clicked
2. You need to retrieve the input field's value as a number using `parseInt()` since input values are treated as strings by default.

```
const num = document.getElementById("numberText");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const button = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

const isEven = (number) => {
    if (number % 2 === 0) {
        return "This number is even";
    } else {
        return "This number is odd";
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const enteredNumber = parseInt(num.value);
    result.textContent = isEven(enteredNumber);
});
```

A shorter way is to do this:

```
const num = document.getElementById("numberText");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const button = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const enteredNumber = parseInt(num.value);
    result.textContent = (number % 2 === 0) ? "This number is even" : "This number is odd";
});
```